# FME AUTOCAD_OD Reader error

Tags: autocad, autocad-map, fme-form

I have a Civil 3d CAD file with an attached object data table. The dwg contains only closed polylines and I have a single ODT defined with 30 fields which include text, integer and double data types. Everything is attached & visible in Civil 3d and data has been entered into the ODT. When I use the 'Autodesk AutoCAD Map 3D Object Data' reader, I get loads of ERROR -BADNEWS feedback that shows that the reader seemingly misreads half my fields mistaking values for column definitions and end up with a mess....
I don't understand why this is happening or what I can do about it. I created a dummy file with one closed polyline and attached the ODT but still run into the same problems. I have tried using 2015.1 32-bit and 2015.0 64-bit but have the same issues.

Comment: ok SAFE software got back to me with good news. The BADNEWS message are not necessarily directly related to the translation process and can be switched off. The real issue is that ODT reader for FME2015 will ignore empty ODT attributes in workbench. They have also informed me that this has been  fixed in the recently released beta of 2016. Great - thanks SAFE!